# Android tests depends on test classes on a library project

Tags: android, testing, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

so my project has two modules:

> - app
> - library

In the `addroidTest` directory of the app, I have some classes that depends on classes located in the `addroidTest` directory of the library.

The structure is:

```
:library /src/main
            /androidTests

:app     /src/main
            /androidTests
```

They compile finely in Android Studio, but when I run the tests I get:

> Error:(6, 32) error: cannot find symbol class XXXX Error:Execution
> failed for task  [...]
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>
> [....]
>
> Execution failed for task > ':app:compileProductionDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac'.

It seems that when gradle executes the task ':app:compileProductionDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac' it cannot find classes located in the test directory of the library.

Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: Are you running Instrumentation or unit tests?

Comment: Instrumentation.   ./gradlew :app:connectedAndroidTest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` source sets are not added to the outputted `jar` and therefore do not exist when `app` looks for `library` code in `androidTest`.  You can place your shared classes in the main lib code and reference it from your `app` there, but I don't think it's possible for you to depend|extend on test classes of another module.

Comment: To further extend the answer, I may point out that I placed my shared classes in the main directory of ANOTHER library module. This library module is imported with "androidTestCompile". This way I am avoiding test classes to be included in the released apk. Only the tests build will include them.

Comment: Is there another solution for this? I have a multi flavor lib with about 5 apps. Each app has specific tests which require test code from the lib. Putting the shared code into it's own test lib would not work as it requires other classes from the lib.

Answer (score -4):

I've worked with Junit and it was located in libs folder as you mentioned. for your test classes you can try these steps:

1- in androidTest folder, make sure you place your test classes in a path like this: androidTest -> java -> com.examples.bla (the same as the project) ->the test class.

2- Go to run/debug configuration ->defaults -> Android Tests (add it if it's not there), then choose "All in Module" for test option, and also make sure that Gradle-aware Make is added at the bottom of the configuration window.